# Spring MVC, attempting to edit but creating new objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an MVC app that is creating new offices instead of updating them on when using an edit form.  Please help me understand why this is happening.

Search method that populates the search results:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchResults", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam String searchCriteria, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<Office> offices = officeServiceImpl.search(searchCriteria);
    return new ModelAndView("searchResults", "offices", offices);
}
```

Here's what the link to the edit form looks like on the search results page:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/office/${office.getId()}/edit" class="btn btn-success">Edit Office</a>
```

Here is the Controller's edit GET method that populates the form with the existing Office:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{officeId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=NoResultException.class)
public ModelAndView initUpdateOfficeForm(
    @PathVariable("officeId") Long officeId, Model model) {
    Office office = officeServiceImpl.find(officeId);
    //prepareEditFormModelAndView(office) just converts some objects to strings for typeahead form population
    return prepareEditFormModelAndView(office);
}
```

Here is the edit POST method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{officeId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processUpdateOfficeForm(@ModelAttribute("office") @Valid Office office,
        BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    if (! "united states of america".equals(office.getFolderStrings().toLowerCase())) {
        //This portion of code converts the typeahead strings to objects
        result = tryCountries(office, result);
        result = tryDepartments(office, result);
        result = tryEmployees(office, result);
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return prepareEditFormModelAndView(office);
    } else {
        officeServiceImpl.save(office);
        status.setComplete();
        return new ModelAndView("editResult", "office", office);
    }
}
```

officeServiceImpl calls officeRepositoryImpl method save which looks like:

```
@Override
public Office save(Office office) {
    em.merge(office);
    em.flush();
    return office;
}
```

Thanks

Edit: Adding prepareEditFormModelAndView(office), This method attempts to build strings from associated objects:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={NoResultException.class, IndexOutOfBoundsException.class})
private ModelAndView prepareEditFormModelAndView(Office office) {
    String departmentStrings = "";
    String employeeStrings = "";

    List<OOM> officeOOMs = new ArrayList<OOM>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        officeOOMs = oomServiceImpl.getOOMsForCurrentOffice(office.getId());
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        officeOOMs = null;
    }
    for (OOM o : officeOOMs) {
        try {
            Employee tempEmployee = employeeServiceImpl.find(o
                    .getEmployeeId());
            sb.append(tempEmployee.getDisplayName() + ", ");
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            sb.append("Not found in system");
        }
    }
    employeeStrings = sb.toString();

    if ((! "".equals(office.getDepartmentStringsOnForm())) && office.getDepartmentStringsOnForm() != null) {
        departmentStrings = office.getDepartmentStringsOnForm();
    }
    String folderStrings = "";
    try {
        folderStrings = kmlFolderServiceImpl.getInternationalOfficeString(office.getId());
        LOGGER.info("Folder Strings: " + folderStrings);
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        folderStrings = "";
        LOGGER.info("Folder Strings: " + "no result");
    }
    boolean isInternational = office.isInternational();
    ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("editOfficeForm", "office", office);
    result.addObject("departmentStrings", departmentStrings);
    result.addObject("isInternational", isInternational);
    result.addObject("folderStrings", folderStrings);
    result.addObject("employeeStrings", employeeStrings);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what does prepareEditFormModelAndView do?

Comment: When you POST office, do you send it's ID as well?

Comment: @geoand, no, I do not pass the ID.  I pass the model attribute of office.

Comment: What @geoand is aiming at is the fact that you'll need to send the ID along with the other attributes when POST'ing data. If the entity's ID/primary key is not set it will be treated as if it's new.

Comment: @Bart, do you recommend I put a hidden attribute with the id on the editOfficeForm?

Comment: @JoeEssey Yes you need to send the ID in a hidden field (or have a means to retrieve it from the Database)

Comment: Or use `@SessionAttributes` to store the object in the session in between requests. When finished processing use `SessionStatus.complete()` to cleanup the used parameters. But you already have the ID as a path variable `{officeId}`. So instead of sending it as a hidden param, simply adding a ` @PathVariable("officeId") Long officeId` to the method and then set that in your model attribute should also fix it (saves you adding the form variable).

Comment: @geoand Might I suggest you add your comment as an answer so that the OP can accept it, seeings that your suggestion did result in working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding a previous comment here, for better clarification. According to the OP the following fixes the problem:

When the ID is not in the form then when the model is posted back no ID is set to the entity making the persistence provider believe it is new entity. 
Therefor the most obvious solution is to post the ID of the entity as well in the save operation (probably using a hidden field).

Another solution would be to try to load the entity in the database based on some business key
to see if the entity is new or not.